# Z3 raises invalid memory access with JNA

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jna, z3

I am using the Z3 C api in java with jna. I often get an invalid memory access, but only with the windows (.dll) and mac os (.dylib) libraries. It does not happen when I use the linux one (.so).

I temporarily solved this problem never calling the `dec_ref` procedures, both for ast and for all the other objects (I still call the `inc_ref` procs, and I use the `mk_context_rc` at the beginning). Of course this solution is not sustainable.

I guess it is due to the memory management somewhere. Even if I just use the `mk_context` it still crashes.

In the thread [JNA simple function call works on linux (x64) but not on windows (x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856149/jna-simple-function-call-works-on-linux-x64-but-not-on-windows-x86) the user experienced a similar problem, and it turned out it was due to some compiling configuration.

This is the exception I get (on Mac OS X 10.6.8)

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000000c
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

and this is the trace of the failure

```
    Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001250d4d64 unsigned int ast_array_hash<expr>(expr* const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 244
1   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001250cb16a ast_manager::register_node_core(ast*) + 36
2   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001250cbeae ast_manager::mk_app_core(func_decl*, unsigned int, expr* const*) + 134
3   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001250cc30d ast_manager::mk_app(func_decl*, unsigned int, expr* const*) + 749
4   libz3.dylib                     0x000000012528c194 map_proc::reconstruct(app*) + 214
5   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001254830b8 void for_each_expr_core<qe::lift_foreign_vars, obj_mark<expr, bit_vector, default_t2uint<expr> >, false, false>(qe::lift_foreign_vars&, obj_mark<expr, bit_vector, default_t2uint<expr> >&, expr*) + 760
6   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001254832c9 qe::lift_foreign_vars::lift(obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&) + 61
7   libz3.dylib                     0x00000001254833a6 qe::datatype_plugin::simplify(obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&) + 92
8   libz3.dylib                     0x000000012546b1a7 qe::quant_elim_plugin::check(unsigned int, app* const*, expr*, obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&, bool, ref_vector<app, ast_manager>&, qe::def_vector*) + 535
9   libz3.dylib                     0x000000012546b8f9 qe::quant_elim_new::eliminate_block(unsigned int, app* const*, obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&, ref_vector<app, ast_manager>&, bool, qe::def_vector*) + 445
10  libz3.dylib                     0x000000012545f2cb qe::quant_elim_new::eliminate_exists(unsigned int, app* const*, obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&, ref_vector<app, ast_manager>&, bool, qe::def_vector*) + 67
11  libz3.dylib                     0x0000000125462170 qe::quant_elim_new::eliminate_exists_bind(unsigned int, app* const*, obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&) + 88
12  libz3.dylib                     0x000000012545c0ba qe::expr_quant_elim::elim(obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&) + 1012
13  libz3.dylib                     0x000000012545cb75 qe::expr_quant_elim::operator()(expr*, expr*, obj_ref<expr, ast_manager>&) + 113
14  libz3.dylib                     0x000000012548b993 qe_tactic::imp::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) + 783
15  libz3.dylib                     0x00000001255debfa cleanup_tactical::operator()(ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) + 14
16  libz3.dylib                     0x00000001255d5e3d exec(tactic&, ref<goal> const&, sref_buffer<goal>&, ref<model_converter>&, ref<proof_converter>&, obj_ref<dependency_manager<ast_manager::expr_dependency_config>::dependency, ast_manager>&) + 109
17  libz3.dylib                     0x0000000125070ed8 _tactic_apply + 680
18  libz3.dylib                     0x00000001250711d9 Z3_tactic_apply + 105
19  jna4404318687023840668.tmp      0x000000010a00cd1c ffi_call_unix64 + 76
20  jna4404318687023840668.tmp      0x000000010a00c884 ffi_call + 644
21  jna4404318687023840668.tmp      0x000000010a003ca5 Java_com_sun_jna_Native_ffi_1prep_1cif + 1605
22  jna4404318687023840668.tmp      0x000000010a004282 Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokePointer + 34
23  ???                             0x00000001031cfd2e 0 + 4347198766
24  ???                             0x00000001031cd658 0 + 4347188824
25  ???                             0xffb89c44ff5c4272 0 + 18426649695542329970
```

maybe they they can be useful to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Why don't you call [ScalaZ3](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/ScalaZ3) from Java? I think it would be much easier.

Comment: On windows, native `long` is the same size for 32-bit and 64-bit.  On OSX and linux, the size differs.  What arch are you running on each platform?  If you're running on different arches and don't account for that in your mapping (which you don't provide any examples of, by the way - you should provide both native and JNA declarations), you'll get memory errors.

Comment: I am running on mac os and windows on 64bits machines, but the linux one is 32bits. Notice that the exception is raised after many calls of this procedure, almost randomly for what I can see.

Comment: ScalaZ3 does not support many functionality I need (like tacticals), that is why I am using jna.

Comment: Try running on linux 64 bit, you'll likely see the same errors.  And run OSX using a 32-bit VM (-d32 should do it).

Comment: Same error on OSX using 32bits VM

Comment: Actually, I realized that if I stess it more I can make it crash with any arch :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception was raised because my main program and the java garbage collector were accessing Z3 concurrently. I solved just making the `Library` object thread-safe, wrapping it with the method [Native.synchronizedLibrary](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#synchronizedLibrary%28com.sun.jna.Library%29)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments in your question, it seems you are using tactics and other features only available in the new Z3 API. Starting at version 4.0, reference counting is the default approach for managing memory in the Z3 API. The Z3 API still has support for the old memory management policy (it is enabled when the API `Z3_mk_context` is used instead of `Z3_mk_context_rc`). However, the old memory management policy is not available for new objects (such as `Solvers`, `Tactics`, ...) that were introduced in version 4.0.

The Z3 distribution contains a Python API. The source code for the Python API is located in the sub-directory `python` in the Z3 distribution. It demonstrates how to integrate the Z3 API in a managed language such as a Python. I believe a similar approach can be used to integrate the Z3 API in Java. The idea is to wrap every Z3 object with a Java object wrapper. The reference counter should be incremented in the constructor, and decremented when the Java garbage collector reclaims the wrapper.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. I create the context using mk_context_rc, I increment the reference counter in the constructor and I decrement the counter in the destructor (finalize) of every wrapper. I think the problem is that the garbage collector runs concurrently. In fact, if I store all the objects to destroy in a synchronized list and then I decrement the counters interrupting the execution of the main program everything works. So I think the problem was that I caused some race condition inside Z3. Is the z3 library supposed to be thread safe?